# emacs term mode not recognizing commands

Tags: emacs

I recently upgraded to emacs 24.4, and whenever I try to execute a command while in the term (e.g. `C-x C-f` to open a file), it will just say `C-x C-f is undefined`.

How can I enable commands to run in the term mode?

Comment: Are you talking about running emacs in a terminal, or terminal emulation mode inside emacs (`M-x term`)? In the latter, a lot of keystrokes are disabled as to let the programs in the terminal handle them - most keys involving `C-x` are remapped to `C-c`, e.g. `C-c C-f` for `find-file`.

Comment: I meant terminal emulation. The `C-c C-f`` keystroke works. Is there a way to configure emacs so that `find-file` will work on`C-x C-f` in terminal emulation mode as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In emacs `term`, a lot of keystrokes are disabled as to let the programs in the terminal handle them - most keys involving `C-x` are remapped to `C-c`, e.g. `C-c C-f` for `find-file`.

If you want to use `term` in the same way as a `shell`, you can change to "line mode" with `C-c C-j`, where keys are processed by emacs. If you want to go back to directly sending keys to the terminal, press `C-c C-k` ("char mode").

Details are in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html).